# empty string or null check within loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var imageArr = [];
if(req.body.photo1){
  imageArr.push(req.body.photo1);
}
if(req.body.photo2){
  imageArr.push(req.body.photo2);
}
if(req.body.photo3){
  imageArr.push(req.body.photo3);
}
if(req.body.photo4){
  imageArr.push(req.body.photo4);
}
```

How to improve above code? I wrote a loop but I got undefined1,undefined2,undefined3,undefined4 value in my array.

```
for(var i = 1; i<=4;i++){
if(req.body.photo+''+i){
imageArr.push(req.body.photo+''+i);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since `"photo" + i` is a variable key, you need to access it as `req.body [ "photo" + 1 ]`

```
for(var i = 1; i<=4;i++)
{
  var value = req.body[ "photo"+ i];
  if( value ) 
  {
    imageArr.push(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: is assigning it to a `value` variable compulsory?